# Overlay specification that is active on show and 2 more slides

Tags: beamer, overlays

Below is the MWE. What I want to happen is:

- Alert1 is shown as alert on display.
- Next click -- alert details are displayed. Alert1 remains Red.
- Next click -- Alert 2 is displayed as alert and both Alert 1 and earlier line go back to normal.

I have tried <.-+> (as shown below) but that does not solve the problem. How do I, say, make this alert when displayed and keep it for the next n clicks (while other text keeps getting displayed)?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item \alert <.,+>{Alert1} \uncover <+-> {alert details}
\item \alert <.,+>{Alert2} \uncover <+-> {alert details}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

OK. The trick is to use offset. This is what works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item \alert <.-.(1)>{Alert1} \uncover <+-> {alert details}
\item \alert <.-.(1)>{Alert2} \uncover <+-> {alert details}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```